# Appropriateness of the word 膣外射精 in average adult conversations?

Tags: words

In discussing the marriage of Jin Akanishi and Meisa Kuroki, and why many young celebrities in Japan seem to fall into shotgun marriages, I wanted to use an equivalent for the term "withdrawal method", a phrase in english that is pretty innocuous. I found 膣外射精, and I was wondering if it was a decent equivalent, or if it was too racy for average conversations? I've seen it translated as withdrawal method and coitus interruptus, which are pretty safe, but translated literally I guess it means  "extra-vaginal ejaculation", which besides being a mouthful to say in English, could be somewhat inappropriate in certain situations. Forgive any unintended puns in the question. Any alternative euphemisms or suggestions are appreciated if warranted.

Comment: As an aside, what is the equivalent term for 'shotgun marriage'?  Is it できちゃったこん?

Comment: i think できちゃった結婚 is most standard but i think I've heard  できちゃったこん or  できこん

Answer (score 2, accepted):

膣外射精 is the technical term. I wouldn't be worried about it being too dirty for conversation, because it is of a technical nature. However, I would worry about it being too literary to be understood in converstion.

You might want to consider [外出]{そとだ}し　instead.